# fread a float array after a fwrite immediately will cause a file offset problem

Tags: c++, c, fread

Initial the integer `array[]` right line 21 will cause the failure of the `data[]` array fread from data.txt .

```
int main()
   {
           FILE * file0 = NULL;
           file0 = fopen("data.txt", "r+");
           if (file0 == NULL)
           {
                   file0 = fopen("data.txt", "w+");
          
                  float array1[2] = {0.5, 0.3};
  
                  fwrite(array1, sizeof(float), 2, file0);
  
  
          }
          else
          {
                  float array1[2] = {0.5, 0.3};
                  fwrite(array1, sizeof(float), 2, file0);
  //              int array[3] = {1,2,3};
  //              fwrite(array, sizeof(int), 3, file0);
          }
          float data[5];
          int data1[5];
  
          fread(data, sizeof(float), 2, file0);
          fclose(file0);
  
  
          printf(" 1. %.2f 2. %.2f\n",data[0], data[1]);
  }
```

As the code shows, the float array1 stores two float elements and fwrite in data.txt. The data array fread the data.txt to get these two float elements.
The result shows like this:

```
~/workplace/testinttofloat$ gcc main.c
~/workplace/testinttofloat$ ./a.out 
 1. 0.50 2. 0.30
```

The result will show like this:

```
~/workplace/testinttofloat$ gcc main.c
~/workplace/testinttofloat$ ./a.out 
 1. 0.50 2. 0.30
~/workplace/testinttofloat$ gcc main.c
~/workplace/testinttofloat$ ./a.out 
 1. 0.00 2. 0.00
```

The reason why `data[]` cannot get the correct results is that I didn't use `rewind` to reposition the file offset, so the `data` just reach the EOF.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry, it looks better now.

Comment: It's much better now! Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @TedLyngmo gcc version 11.2.0 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2)

Comment: Then add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and you'll get good help.

Comment: I just get two warnings that there are two arrays that are not used. ```~/workplace/testinttofloat$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:21: warning: unused variable ‘array’ [-Wunused-variable]
   21 |                 int array[3] = {1,2,3};
        |                     ^~~~~
main.c:25:13: warning: unused variable ‘data1’ [-Wunused-variable]
   25 |         int data1[5];
        |             ^~~~~
```

Comment: @Aganju the parameter r+ means read and write, I check it with man fopen, do I need to use another way to open the file?

Comment: Once you've written to the file you need to `rewind` or seek back to the beginning to be able to read what you wrote. You should always check the return values from i/o functions to be sure the operation was performed successfully and completely.

Comment: Thank you dude!!!! I know what happens now. btw, how to pin your comment at the top? @RetiredNinja

Comment: @RetiredNinja it's open again.